# XML response processed into .html file

Tags: html, xml, linq-to-xml

Using C#, I'm required to pick up some data from a certain URL and then produce a very basic .html file that displays a list of university courses available.  The response from the URL is XML that looks something like this

```
<ArrayOfCourse xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Demo.Samples">
   <Course>
      <codeField>String content</codeField>
      <semesterField>String content</semesterField>
      <titleField>String content</titleField>
   </Course>
   ...
</ArrayOfCourse>
```

I've been instructed that I should be using classes like XDocument and XmlTextWriter to produce the desired html.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--courses-->
<html>
   <head>
      <title>courses</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>courses</h1>
      <p>COMPSCI 101: <b>Principles of Programming</b><br />Summer School; Semester 1; Semester 2</p>
      ...
      ...
   </body>
```

My question is, how do you go about doing this? More specifically, what method is used to get each tag out of the response? Can anyone give me any useful references for example? I've had a look myself but can't seem to find anything overly useful.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment, or a project where you've been directed to use XDocument and XmlTextWriter?  This is something that is more properly done with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);

var q = from b in xml.Descendants("product")
        select new
        {
            name = (string)b.Element("name"),
            price = (double?)b.Element("price"),                    
            extra = (string)b.Element("extra1"),
            deeplink = (string)b.Element("deepLink")                   
        };
```

or

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/";

foreach (XElement element in doc.Root
                                .Element(ns + "fields")
                                .Elements(ns + "field"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}; Value: {1}",
                      (string) element.Attribute("name"),
                      (string) element.Element(ns + "value"));
}
```